# Connecting mobile and desktop application

Tags: c#, android, jquery-mobile, mobile, desktop

- I wrote an application in C#. Application requires an internet
  connection all the time. What i want to do is leading it from my
  mobile phone.
- e.g. My mobile app will have two buttons one of them says "stop
  process" and other says "start process". When user taps any of them,
  app will send data to desktop app and desktop version will do.
  Directly, real-time control from mobile phone.
- You can imagine it as a small, tiny, little TeamViewer Mobile App which
  allows to control your pc via mobile phone.
- I don't know how to start. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your desktop application you can use an object of class [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and in you mobile app you can call the url (using a web client object) of your desktop application. At the end of the page in the link you can find an example of HttpListener.

In this [link](https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx) you will find an example of HttpListener.

Comment: Can i do it with tcp client and server?

Comment: Yes you can do it with tcp client and server, but I prefer the solution with http because the information can pass through a firewall that only allows HTTP traffic. Additionally, if your app grow you need to implement more logic in the tcp server socket, because you will need larger packets so you need to implement a fifo buffer to process the request, whereas the HttpListener make all the work for you, and you only need to read the url request and parameters.

Comment: okay, got it. However, how can i do it with HttpListener? Any examples?

Comment: Look the example link thay I wrote in the answer. Remember mark the answer as correct if the solution is well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a web server involved somewhere - cos if so then look at SignalR as a simple means of real-time communications.

http://www.asp.net/signalr